# How to know whether a local keybinding map exists (for a given package) and its name

Tags: key-bindings, help, pdf-tools

I was wondering if we can know whether a given package has a local map of keybindings. For example, I'd like to bind the function `pdf-occur` of the `pdf-tools` package by using the `use-package` macro. This would entail doing something like:

```
(use-package pdf-tools
  :map pdf-tools-mode-map  ## ??? this is what I need to know: is there a local map? What's its name?
   ("s-o"  . pdf-occur))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of alternative ways to find out:

- Use `C-h m` to see a description of the major mode.  It may mention the keymap variable (e.g. `pdf-tools-mode-map`) or key bindings in it.  If it mentions only bindings (not the keymap variable), use `C-h k` followed by one of those bindings.  The `*Help*` buffer will tell you the name of the keymap (the variable name) where that key is bound for the mode.
- Use `C-h v` followed by the name of your major mode (e.g. `pdf-tools-mode`) and `-map`, then `TAB`, to see if there's a variable with that name (e.g. `pdf-tools-mode-map`).

Comment: Awesome! Your tips have helped me find a `pdf-isearch-minor-mode` where the `pdf-occur` function is defined. I haven't found a `pdf-isearch-minor-mode-map` explicitly, but defining my keybinding there makes it work whenever I am in a PDF document so I guess it exists? Thank you!

Comment: Thank Emacs and its `C-h m` and `C-h v`. ;-)